# Get properties of git bash terminal on windows

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, git-bash, msysgit

What is the command to get all main properties of opened **git bash terminal** on windows (version, type of terminal)

**Edit:**
Running `bash --version` returns

```
GNU bash, version 3.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Since **git bash** is fork of **msys** with git, I want to know what version of **msys** is used?
Only what changes is just git version for this terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uname --all
```

```
-a, --all
  print all information, in the following order:
  kernel name
  network node hostname
  kernel release
  kernel version
  machine hardware name
  processor type or "unknown"
  hardware platform or "unknown"
  operating system
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/4e0992f8c1d6ed7571c0f27b/baby-cygwin.sh#L13)

[explainshell.com - uname --all](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=uname+--all)